# Proving a distribution function is continuous at irrational points

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

Let $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ be a collection of rational points from the interval $[0, 1]$. A random variable $X$ takes on $x_n$ with probability $1/2^{n}$. Prove the distribution function $F_{X}(x)$ of $X$ is continuous at every irrational point $x$.

---

I am pretty sure this type of question will involve a density argument by using the fact that the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (I'm not completely sure -- this is just my guess from other problems).

I'm really not too sure how to proceed though because they also gave us a collection of rational points as well. I don't really see how to combine both of these facts to show continuity.

Also, some other problems I've solved use inequalities like Markov's and Chebyshev's, but I can't really do that here since there's no expectation.

I would greatly appreciate your help. I am trying to get better at these sort of problems.

Comment: Hint: For every irrational you have sequence of rationals converging to it.

Comment: Fix any $\epsilon>0$ and irrational $r \in [0,1]$. Since $F$ is monotone, it is enough to find such rational numbers $p,q \in [0,1]$ such that $p <r<q$ and both : $F(r) - F(p)$, $F(q) - F(r)$ are less than $\epsilon$. Note that starting from some $N \ in \mathbb N$ we have $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} < \epsilon$. So get rid of all those rationals $x_i$ for $i <N$ and as $p,q$ choose rationals that are "closer" to $r$ than any of those $x_i$ (we can get rid of them as there's finitelly many of them).

Comment: @joesx The term "probability distribution" is ambiguous (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_function). All answers here seem to assume it to mean a cumulative distribution function but I suspect the author meant a probability density function instead. Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

The argument here is actually analysis, not probability at all.

$$F_X(x):= P(X \leq x)=\sum_{n \geq 1}{2^{-n}1(x \geq x_n)}.$$

The series is normally convergent, and, if $x$ is irrational, each term is continuous at $x$. So the sum of the series is also continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$F_X$ is an increasing right-continuous function. So it is continuous at a point $x$ iff $F_X(x)=F_X(x-)$  where $F_X(x-)$ is the left hand limit at $x$. Also, $P(X=x)=\lim P(X-\frac 1 n < X \leq x)=\lim [F_X(x)-F_X(x-\frac 1 n)]=F_X(x)=F_X(x-)$. Hence $F_X$ is continuous at $x$ iff $P(X=x)=0$. For $x$ irrational $P(X=x)=0$ so $F_X$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: So we don't need the fact that the probability is $1/2^{n}$ for rational points?

Comment: No, $F_X$ is continuous at $x$ iff $P(X=x)=0$. @joesx

Comment: So you didn't need density either?

Comment: @joesx The conclusion is true for any discrete random variable whose values are all rational. The actual distribution does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{r_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.
Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$ be the cumulative distribution
function of $X$. Note that $F(x)$ is explicitly given by 
$$
F(x)=\sum\left\{ \frac{1}{2^{n}}\mid r_{n}\leq x\right\} .
$$
Let $x_{0}\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.
Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $\delta=\min\{|r_{n}-x_{0}|\mid1\leq n\leq N\}>0$, then $(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)\cap\{r_{n}\mid1\leq n\leq N\}=\emptyset$.
For any $x_{1},x_{2}\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$ with $x_{1}<x_{2}$,
we have that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 & \leq & F(x_{2})-F(x_{1})\\
 & = & \sum\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\mid r_{n}\in(x_{1},x_{2}]\}\\
 & \leq & \sum\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\mid r_{n}\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)\}\\
 & \leq & \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $F$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any irrational point and look at its neighborhood containing none of the $x_i$ (why must this exist). $F_X$ is constant in this neighborhood and hence is continuous

Edit: This also means $F_X$ is continuous at every point except the $x_i$

Comment: Actually that neighbourhood does not exist

Comment: There are a finite number of these rational points, there is a small enough neighbourhood not containing any of them. I'm not saying this neighbourhood should contain *no* rational points

Comment: The sequence is not finite; there can be one (or many) accumulation points.